# If statement fault in python

Tags: python

I executed the following code:

```
import sys

x=sys.argv[1]

print x;

if x > 1:
    print "It's greater than 1"
```

and here is the output:

```
C:\Python27>python abc.py 0
0
It's greater than 1
```

How the hell it's greater than 1? in fact the if condition should fail, is there any fault with my code?

Comment: replace 'print x' with 'print x + 1', and you'll understand!

Comment: @Nitesh: Welcome to SO.  Please "accept" one of the correct answers by clicking the "check mark" at the left of the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because type of `x` in `x=sys.argv[1]` is `str`.

```
import sys
x = sys.argv[1]
print type(x)
```

Output =`<type 'str'>`

So in python,

```
>>> '0'>1
True
```

Therefore you need

```
>>> int('0')>1
False
>>>
```

Answer (score 3):

`x` is a string but `1` is an integer, so the comparison is of mismatched types. You need something like `if int(x) > 1:`.

Comment: oh awesome, thanks. I'm a beginner just started to learn python

Answer (score 3):

This is testing x (a string).
try using:

```
if int(x) > 1: 
     print "It's greater than 1"
```

I got curious about this and found:

[How does Python compare string and int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3270680/how-does-python-compare-string-and-int)